# Shown that this matrix is a representative of a group.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I have to show that this matrix (for which $ad - bc = 1$)
\begin{pmatrix}
 a & b & 0\\
 c & d & 0 \\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
is a representative of a group. The same for this one:

\begin{pmatrix}
 a & 0& b \\
 0 & 1 & 0\\
 c & 0 & d
\end{pmatrix}

So I've already shown that (the hard way, by calculating everything out),
but I wonder if there's a faster way of doing it - for example by showing, that they are similar to this one \begin{pmatrix}
 a & b \\
 c & d
\end{pmatrix}
because the (0 0 1)-row does not affect the rest. Any ideas?

Comment: Hints: The invertible matrices which stabilize non-zero vector subspace form a subgroup and the invertible matrices  which stabilize a $2$-dimensional subspace form a subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2\times 2$ matrices with non-zero determinant $1$ is the group $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ which is a subset of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ ($2\times 2$ matrices). However the injective map taking 
$\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
a&b\\ c&d
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)\in SL_2(\mathbb{C}) $ to $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
a&b&0\\ c&d&0\\0&0&1
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)\in SL_3(\mathbb{C}) $ is a monomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

The group  $SL(2)\times 1\simeq SL(2)$ consists of such matrices you have given.